# Array to string conversion error when inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to insert data into the database using form but I'm getting error. What can I do to solve this?

I've tried several way to debug it but not working.

**Error**:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Employ\index.php on line 36

**Code**:

```php
$country = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['country']);
$zip = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['zip']);
$identity =($_FILES['identity']);
$fileName = $_FILES['identity']['name'];
$fileTmpName = $_FILES['identity']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['identity']['size'];
$fileError = $_FILES['identity']['error'];
$fileType = $_FILES['identity']['type'];
$fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
$allow = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png',);
if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allow)) {
    if ($fileError === 0) {
        if ($fileSize < 1000000) {
            $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true) . "." . $fileActualExt;
            $fileDestination = 'uploads/' . $fileNameNew;
            move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO applicants (name, email, gender, dob, mobile, accounts, occupation, ssn, m_status, address1, address2, city, country, zip, identity) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$gender', '$dob', '$mobile', '$accounts', '$occupation', '$ssn', '$m_status', '$address1', '$address2', '$city', '$country', '$zip', '$identity')";
            $insert = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png',)` is invalid.

Comment: What could be the correct one here

Comment: Think what could be wrong with the code that I have just posted. There's only 26 characters to debug :) That line is directly tied into the line that follows it. What is the logic attempting to do there? Once you understand that, you'll see the error.

Comment: I have corrected it to array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'); yet it still throwing same error

Comment: the trailing comma is perfectly valid. which is line 36? have you checked the files array is populated?

Comment: @Dharman, I'm aware of this and I'm just doing this for this first time. I'm still learning.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error is due to using $identity array as a string

```
$identity =($_FILES['identity']);



$sql = "INSERT INTO applicants (name, email, gender, dob, mobile, accounts, occupation, ssn, m_status, address1, address2, city, country, zip, identity) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$gender', '$dob', '$mobile', '$accounts', '$occupation', '$ssn', '$m_status', '$address1', '$address2', '$city', '$country', '$zip', '$identity')";
```

Also you may consider using PDO for interacting with databases.

Comment: I don't know how to use PDO. I'm know to the world of programming.